# JBoss EAP 6.3 JMS maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jms

I've been googling quite a bit, but I don't seem to be able to find what Maven dependency I need to be able to use the java.jms package when working with JBoss EAP 6.3. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jboss eap 6.3.0 [quickstarts](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/6.3.0.GA) use the following dependency:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I've used this one without problems

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

To be honest, I'm not so sure what is the difference between them.. but I'm confident either one will work.

Hope it helps!